# How do you Force Type Decimal Number to always Round Up to 2dp

Tags: python-2.7, decimal, rounding

E.g. 23.122 will round to 23.13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you need to use Math and ceil for this and the code looks something like below

```
   >>> import math
   >>> print(math.ceil(23.122*100)/100)
   >>>23.13
```

Here you multiply your number with 100 and then divide and find its ceil value

Comment: You should be aware that this answer doesn't always give you the results you expect. For example, `math.ceil(9.13 * 100) / 100` is `9.14`.

Comment: @MarkDickinson, yes you are right just checked it. Is there an alternative ?

Comment: So the general rule is: if you care about precise decimal rounding, you should probably use Python's `Decimal` type (from the `decimal` module). There are other possible workarounds that work in more specific cases.